# How to keep an xml extension but load from a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to load resources from page2 when requesting page1?

For example I have the url: http://site.ru/sitemap.xml

I want to load data from page: http://site.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap but I also want to keep the URL http://site.ru/sitemap.xml

Comment: `file_get_contents()`  ?

Comment: whether there options with htaccess? Or it can only redirect?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite the link ?

Comment: No , I want to keep this link , but get content from another URL

Comment: My answer will achieve what you require

Comment: @Zanderwar when I quering site.ru/sitemap.php  - all OK , it loading source from http://site.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap , but when trying site.ru/sitemap.xml - nothing happens

Comment: Make sure you have the mod_rewrite extension enabled, check your `phpinfo();` for it. If you don't have it, ask your host to install/enable it, they will likely say yes :)

Comment: @Zanderwar , sorry missed something when typed. ALL FINE!

Comment: Glad to have helped you, enjoy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to rewrite the URL using mod_rewrite (Apache), if you wish to keep the `.xml` extension.

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$   sitemap.php
```

**sitemap.php**:

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo file_get_contents("http://site.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap")
?>
```

Or if you want to avoid making sitemap.php all together

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$   index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
```

Comment: I used your solution, all fine. I want to ask You , why I can't just write something  like `RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ http://site.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap`?

Comment: You mean the full URL? Probably some configuration restriction?